# Jenkins-AndroidEmulator Plugin-Failed to create avd

Tags: android, jenkins-plugins, appium-android

@All,

I have written appium script for testing mobile app and on windows it works like charm (i use Genymotion as android emulator) but on production i have Centos 7 server (with graphical interface), here i tried to open headless android emulator with the help of 'Jenkins-AndroidEmulator plugin 3.0) with maven and before running my maven command i tried to create aavd emulator with following configuration:-
[image] 
and on the centos7 i have installed android-26.
But when i run my build it throws below error:-

```
[android] Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk
[android] Creating Android AVD: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_480_WVGA_android-26_x86_test.avd
[android] /opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -f -c 32M -n hudson_en-US_480_WVGA_android-26_x86_test -k system-images;android-26;default;x86

    Loading local repository...                                                     
    [=========                              ] 25% Loading local repository...       
    [=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
    [=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
    [=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
    [=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...       
    Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:
    null

[android] Failed to run AVD creation command
[android] Could not create Android emulator: Failed to run AVD creation command
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you find any solution ? As far I know, default inside jenkins is not recognised, try to execute this command manually `/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -f -c 32M -n hudson_en-US_480_WVGA_android-26_x86_test -k system-images;android-26;google_apis_playstore;x86`

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem as you, but the Console Output says:

```
[android] /Users/jenkins/.android-sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -f -c 64M -n hudson_en-US_420_1080x1920_android-26_x86_Nexus-5X -k system-images;android-26;default;x86
Loading local repository...                                                     
[=========                              ] 25% Loading local repository...       
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...       
Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:
system-images;android-24;default;x86_64
system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86_64
system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-25;android-wear;x86
system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86_64
```

So I changed **Target ABI** to *x86_64*, and **Android OS version** to *7.0* to match **"system-images;android-24;default;x86_64"**

Then the emulator works fine:

> [android] Emulator is ready for use (took 84 seconds)